# Can't start MySQL server on MacOS

Tags: mysql, macos, popsql

I am a complete newbie to MySQL and just installed it on my Mac. I am pretty sure I set the PATH to `/usr/local/mysql/bin/`

I'm running into a number of issues and would appreciate help on any of them:

1. When I try and connect to my db on PopSQL I get the following error (pretty sure I'm using all the proper settings):

`Uh oh :( Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

2. I tried the command `sudo mysql.server start` but got the error:

`sudo: mysql.server: command not found` although I know mysql works since I can run `mysql --version`

I didn't expect to run into so many issues even before I started doing any SQL...

Comment: How did you install MySQL? This is where tools like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac) come in handy.

Comment: I installed the MySQL community server and followed the instructions there https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ Would it be better to use Homebrew to install it?

Comment: Personally I prefer Homebrew, it gives you more options especially with regard to the specific version you want, but there are many ways to do it. The important thing is to check with `launchctl` that it's actually running.

Comment: How can I use `launchctl` to check that its running? I tried `mysql -u root -p` and was able to connect but is this different?

Comment: If you can connect it's probably running. `mysql` the command-line tool is likely looking in a different spot for the `mysqld.sock` file. Figure out where that is and configure your other tools accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to first define the MySQL path in the paths file.  To do that, type the following command in the terminal and provide the password:

`sudo nano /etc/paths`

Then, include these lines:

`/usr/local/mysql/bin`

`/usr/local/mysql/support-files`

It should look like this:

[Terminal Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUCgH.png)

Press CTL+O to save.  Then press CTL+X to Exit.  Make sure you restart the terminal (quit and reopen). You should be able to run the `sudo mysql.server start` command now.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -p
```

You need to know root password (usually the same for a single user)